# How to populate a field with $lookup in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

In my project I want to go inside (populate) the `project` field `1`.

I am using the following aggregation query to get data from two collections:

```
Investment.aggregate([

            {
                $project: {
                    year: { $year: "$date" },
                    month: { $month: "$date" },
                    _id: 1,
                    convAmt: 1
                },
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: { year: "$year", month: "$month" },
                    totalInvestMonthy: { $sum: "$convAmt" },
                    amount: {
                        $push: '$convAmt',
                    },
                }
            },{
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'investments',
                    foreignField: "convAmt",
                    localField: "amount",
                    "as": 'users_docs'
                },

            },{
                $match: {
                    "_id.year": year, // year is passed in params
                }
            },

        ]),
```

and the **result** of code is the JSON, below

```
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "year": 2020,
                "month": 2
            },
            "totalInvestMonthy": 650.98,
            "amount": [
                374.03,
            ],
            "users_docs": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e6a140ab1fdbf34c86322e5",
                    "project": "5e68842bfa26a40830a30823",    // I want to populate here
                    "date": "2020-02-21T10:50:32.000Z",
                    "convAmt": 374.03,
                    "user": "5e2ea3b25a436604ecf558b3",
                    "username": "Zeeshan2016",

                },
            ]
        },
```

I want the final result like below in a single object; 
I don't want a separate object just for `project`

```
 "users_docs": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e6a140ab1fdbf34c86322e5",
                    "project":{
                           "_id": "5e688cd02369930b581ec5f7",
                            "projectName": "KhataBook Andorid" 
                              }
                    "convAmt": 374.03,
                    "username:"zeeshan4019"
                     "user": "5e2ea3b25a436604ecf558b3",
                },
            ]
```

Comment: It would help if you can share sample documents for all the documents.

Comment: I did some grammar corrections to make the content easier to read. Please note that you should take the time to capitalize "i" ("I") when referring to self. That is correct English grammar and is annoying for others when it's written small. Also, to make special terms in the text that have to do with code more easily recognizable, it's a good idea to format them as code, using the tool button of the editor. (In this case, "project" is part of the "code", so I formatted it to stand out.)